# Display dialogue from AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, dialog, widget

Let's say I have a basic widget with a button. When i click on this button I would like to display a input dialogue window, still on top of the home screen, where upon entering some value and clicking submit I will see the home screen again.

What I do now is to start an activity with a dialogue which is placed on top of the main activity in my application. Perhaps there is just a simple flag to hide the main activity?

Thankful for any help.

Comment: I figured it out. Just needed to add "android:launchMode="singleInstance" to the manifest for my activity. Will post an answer later when I have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, this is what needed to be put in the manifest for my dialog activity.

```
<activity android:name=".InputDialog" 
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```